# Coldfusion recursive function for Oracle 9i database table

Tags: oracle, recursion, coldfusion

I have the following problem: I have table, in an Oracle 9i database, that has a list of locations, each location has sub locations, and each sub has another sub locations also. I want to make a function to get all the child locations for a certain location.

This is what I did (it is not working)

```
<cffunction name="getLocationHierarchy" access="public" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="locationID"    type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="subLocations"  type="string" required="no" default="">

        <cfquery name="qry_getLocation">
            select ID from locations l
                where l.parentlocationid = #locationID#
        </cfquery>
        <cfif qry_getLocation.recordCount>
            <cfset ListAppend(subLocations,qry_getLocation.ID)>
            <cfset getLocationHierarchy(qry_getLocation.ID,subLocations)>
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn subLocations>
    </cffunction>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is `qry_getLocation.recordCount` always equal to 1 or 0? Otherwise you need to process each record that it returns. Going off at a tangent - have a read about the nested set model - really handy for storing hierachical data : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: the record count returns 1 or more records so I have updated the code to loop on the query but I still got only 2 or 3 values where I should get about 16

Comment: Which database you are using ? SqlServer ?

Comment: If you are using oracle database, then look for [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm).

Comment: 9g? I thought it was 9i or 10g? Either way, 9 does `CONNECT BY PRIOR`, which is what you want to be using here to do the work on the DB side, not the application side. The approach you are attempting won't scale on the application site. Side note: always VAR your variables in in functions. Especially those being called recursively!

Comment: Thank you adam... my mistacke sorry I use oracle 9i

Comment: @HamzehHirzallah - Glad you solved it. Though for next time, phrases like "not working" are very ambiguous :) Be sure to describe what the code is *actually* doing - and what it *should* be doing instead.   Also, as Adam mentioned, proper scoping is critical with recursive functions. Be sure to `VAR` (or `Local`) scope to your function local variables. Otherwise, you could end up introducing some hard to track threading problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by doing the following query

```
SELECT *
   FROM locations l
   START WITH l.id = 35
   CONNECT BY PRIOR l.ID = l.parentlocationid
```

now I can get the data I want, thanks

Comment: Also add LEVEL "LevelNumber" in select which return the hierarchy level